# "Last Name" calculated field from person field

Tags: calculated-column, person

I've got a field "Person" of type person or group which always contains a single value.

I need another column to display that person's last name.

Is it possible to achieve using a calculated field?

Using a workflow with another person field (last name only) would over-complicate things...

Comment: With calculated column, i dont think its possible. you can use jquery to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, its not possible to achieve this using a calculated column, SharePoint does not allow you to insert a "Person or Group" column into a "Calculated" field's formula. Better option is to use SharePoint designer workflow as mentioned below,

1. Create a new text column in the list.
2. Create a workflow and use Update item in this list Action > Add the new text column to the value in people and group column.

Then you can add the text column in calculate formula.

Comment: Thanks, thought so... I've ended up adding another person column with `Show field:` set to `Last Name` and then set up a workflow to set that field to my initial "Person" field's value on item change :)